# WPF Data binding один ко многим

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

Есть DTO IOption класс ObjectGroupOptions. Который может меняться со временем из-за изменения файла конфигурации.

Стоит задача слушать изменения DTO IOption в разных ViewModel.

Из очевидных пришли следующие решения:

- Pub/Sub. Подписываться на изменения в DTO IOption классе в нужных ViewModel. И после в самих ViewModel через рефлексию и аттрибутов устанавливать полученное значение.:

```csharp
private void OnOptionChange(string optionName, string propertyName, object value)
{
    var property = GetType().GetProperties()
        .FirstOrDefault(property =>
            string.Equals(property.Name, propertyName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) &&
            property.GetCustomAttribute<BindToOptionAttribute>() is not null &&
            string.Equals(
                property.GetCustomAttribute<BindToOptionAttribute>()?.optionPropertyName,
                optionName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

    property?.SetValue(this, value);
}
```

Но решил отложить подобное решение на крайний случай.

- Из еще одного решения - Rx/ReactiveUI. Но решил отказаться от подобного решения, так как тянет множество за собой кода, в такой небольшой части проекта.
- И после поиска было найдено интересно решение в виде Bindings в WPF. Что позволяет сделать так:

```csharp
public class ObjectGroupOptions : FrameworkElement 
{
    private static readonly Type ThisType = typeof(ObjectGroupOptions);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FirstObjectEnableProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(FirstObjectEnable), typeof(bool),
            ThisType, new PropertyMetadata(default(bool)));
    
    public bool FirstObjectEnable
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(FirstObjectEnableProperty);
        set => SetValue(FirstObjectEnableProperty, value);
    }
}
```

ObjectGroupOptions наследует FrameworkElement, чтобы было удобнее делать Binding в самом классе.
И в конструкторе ViewModel можно сделать так

```csharp
public class FirstViewModel 
{
    private readonly ObjectGroupOptions old;
    public bool FirstObjectEnable {get; set;}

    public FirstViewModel(IOptionsMonitor<ObjectGroupOptions> optionsMonitor)
    {
        this.optionsMonitor.OnChange(Listener);
        old = optionsMonitor.CurrentValue;
        
        var bingind = new Binding(nameof(FirstObjectEnable)) { Source = this, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
    }
    
    private void Listener(ObjectGroupOptions arg1, string? arg2)
    {
        BindingOperations.ClearBinding(old, ObjectGroupOptions.FirstObjectEnableProperty);

        var bingind = new Binding(nameof(FirstObjectEnable)) { Source = this, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
        arg1.SetBinding(ObjectGroupOptions.FirstObjectEnableProperty, bingind);
    }
}
```

Это отлично будет работать, до тех пор, пока не понадобится добавить в другой ViewModel, еще один Binding к такому же DependencyProperty. Или же если View будет устанавливать новое значение для ObjectGroupOptions из-за чего Binding меняется.

```csharp
public partial class ObjectsGroupSettings
{
    private readonly IOptionsMonitor<ObjectGroupOptions> objectGroupOptionsMonitor;

    public ObjectsGroupSettings(IOptionsMonitor<ObjectGroupOptions> optionsMonitor)
    {
        objectGroupOptionsMonitor = optionsMonitor;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnCheckBoxGroupChange(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is not CheckBox checkbox) return;
        if (checkbox.IsChecked == null) return;

        var objectGroupProperty = ObjectGroupOptionsType?.GetProperties()
            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.Contains(checkbox.Name.Replace("CheckBox", "")));

        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(objectGroupProperty);

        objectGroupProperty.SetValue(objectGroupOptionsMonitor.CurrentValue, checkbox.IsChecked.Value);

    }
}
```

Было найдено решение в виде биндинга один ко многим, как-то так:

```csharp
public ObjectsGroupSettings()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(FirstCheckBox, CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty);

    FirstChild.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, binding);
    SecondChild.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, binding);
    ThirdChild.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, binding);
}
```

Вопрос, как сделать подобный биндинг один ко многим для ObjectGroupOptions и его слушателей ViewModels.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Во-первых, BindingOperations нечего делать во вьюмоделях (если конечно это не внутренние вьюмодели вида). Во-вторых, не очень понятная проблема. Ну подписались вы на аналог INPC, а дальше что? Он должен переписать свойства во вьюмодели с теми же именами что ли? Почему не сделать это явно для каждого нужного свойства?

Comment: @vitidev Добрый день.

>BindingOperations нечего делать во вьюмоделях. Да, но нет. Механизм Binding делает тоже самое, если бы я делал через рефлексию и INPC, вот меня и занитересовало. А можно ли ради интереса сделать через магию BindingOperations.

>Почему не сделать это явно для каждого нужного свойства, так как вызов свойства должны изменять отображение View. То есть property?.SetValue(this, value); вызывает изменения в проперти viewModel, а проперти потом меняет отображение во View через onpropertychanged

Comment: То есть. ViewModels слушают IOption и у себя меняют обновляют проперти следовательно и view динамически.

Comment: 1 Можете запилить свой биндинг, но использовать из вида во вьюмоделях нельзя 2 вообще не понимаю причем тут DependencyProperty. У вас проблема - вы хотите сделать биндинг с DTO на свойства вьюмодели (а то, что потом там еще вид обновит себя - дело десятое). Ну напишите свою реализацию биндинга, который будет принимать лямбду для реакции на изменения свойства по аналогии с [этим](https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/07/11/one-way-to-avoid-messy-propertychanged-event-handling/) или использовать рефлексию. Ваш огород не понимаю

Comment: @vitidev Спасибо большое, пойду смотреть. Просто интересно было попробовать, а почему бы не сделать через DependencyProperty, раз есть такой механизм связывания данных между DTO и свойствами ViewModel. Просто любопытство.

Comment: Делать можно как хочется. Главное не нарушать правило "вьюмодель не знает о виде ничего". Вот чтобы можно было удалить весь WPF и заменить его хоть на консольный вывод, а вьюмодели переписывать не придется совсем. Это правильный MVVM